# How can I run corda nodes on different devices? Not in virtual machines but in actual PC s?

Tags: java, blockchain, nodes, corda, corda-flow

```
detectPublicIp=false
devMode=true
myLegalName="O=PartyB,L=Colombo,C=LK"
p2pAddress="[ip address of machine1]:10008"
rpcSettings {
    address="0.0.0.0:10009"
    adminAddress="0.0.0.0:10049"
}
security {
    authService {
        dataSource {
            type=INMEMORY
            users=[
                {
                    password=test
                    permissions=[
                        ALL
                    ]
                    user=user1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
sshd {
    port=2222
}
```

This is my party a node configuration. I have another 2 nodes in the same machine including a notary and another two nodes in another machine.(The second machine not contain notary) Is there any way that I can do transactions?